# Creating a alias command for bash with unsing name for mkdir

Tags: jquery, bash, backbone.js, terminal, underscore.js

I want to create a command in my terminal that create a basic structure of archives

`terminal: bone` (that will create a basic structure in my folder that looks like this:)

```
├── index.html
└── js
    └── vendor
        ├── backbone.js
        └── underscore.js
```

for that too happen I created in my bash profile this function

```
> bone() {
>     touch index.html
>     mkdir js
>     mkdir js/vendor
>     curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js >
> js/vendor/backbone.js
>     curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js
> > js/vendor/underscore.js
> 
> }
```

Now I want to create a command that when I type

```
terminal: bone newproject
```

creates a folder with the name newproject and inside all the files from the bone function.

```
└── newproject
   └──index.html
   └── js
      └── vendor
          ├── backbone.js
          └── underscore.js
```

Can anyone help me ? tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function:

```
bone() {
  mkdir -p "./$1/js/vendor"
  touch "./$1/index.html"
  curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js > "./$1/js/vendor/backbone.js"
  curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js > "./$1/js/vendor/underscore.js"
 }
```

Usage (examples):

```
bone
bone newproject
```